# How to use a remote server as a proxy to download file?

Tags: ssh, wget, scp, proxy

There are some http file links I can not access, but I have a remote server which can access them.

To download these files to my machine, I use the remote server as a "proxy". This is what I did:

1. `ssh` to remote server
2. execute `wget` command on remote server to download the file
3. transfer the downloaded file to my machine through `scp` command

I want to ask if there exist more convenient method to achieve it? like:

```
some_command root@server http://xxxxx/file.zip ~/Desktop/
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

*ssh* provides a convenient TCP SOCKS5 proxy mode with its [-D](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1#D)/[DynamicForward](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#DynamicForward) option (let's use the default SOCKS port: 1080, you can use any port as long as its referenced in the later settings):

```
ssh -D 1080 someuser@server
```

You can instead run the *ssh* command in background so it stays available without needing to keep it in a terminal for later:

```
ssh -f -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -D 1080 someuser@server
```

Unfortunately `wget` itself doesn't support the SOCKS protocol. `curl` is fine with it with either:

```
export http_proxy=socks5h://localhost:1080/ https_proxy=socks5h://localhost:1080/
curl -o ~/Desktop/file.zip http://xxxxx/file.zip
```

or just:

```
curl --socks5-hostname localhost:1080 -o ~/Desktop/file.zip http://xxxxx/file.zip
```

If you really need `wget` you must use a wrapper. For example there's [`proxychains`](https://manpages.debian.org/proxychains/proxychains.1) which relies on [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#ENVIRONMENT) interception (there are others, like [dante](https://www.inet.no/dante/)'s [`socksify`](https://manpages.debian.org/dante-client/socksify.1) client wrapper working in a similar way or [`redsocks`](https://manpages.debian.org/redsocks/redsocks.8) which itself relies on a special firewall setup for interception).

```
mkdir ~/.proxychains
(echo strict_chain; echo proxy_dns; echo '[ProxyList]'; echo socks5 127.0.0.1 1080) > ~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf

proxychains wget http://xxxxx/file.zip ~/Desktop/
```

Answer (score 2):

If the remote machine has an HTTP proxy (like `squid` or certain configurations of apache's httpd), you could issue the request through that.  `env http_proxy=http://server:3128/ wget http://xxxxx/file.zip`

If the remote machine has a SOCKS or SOCKS5 proxy, you could issue the request through that, but it might need something other than `wget`.

If your SSH login is clean, you could do something like:

```
ssh -n user@server wget -O- http://xxxxx/file.zip >~/Desktop/file.zip
```

Personally, I would usually do the remote `wget`, and then transfer the file with `rsync`.